# Update texture in fragment shader in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader

I'm trying to update texture in fragment shader without any luck. Looks like shader reads texture just once and then no updates. Here is my code:

1. Shader init

   ```
   CCGLProgram *shader = [[CCGLProgram alloc] initWithVertexShaderFilename:@"vertex.vsh" fragmentShaderFilename:@"fragment.fsh"];
   [shader addAttribute:@"P" index:0];
   [shader addAttribute:@"Cl" index:1];
   [shader addAttribute:@"st" index:2];
   [shader link];
   [shader updateUniforms];
   mutableSprite.shaderProgram = shader;
   uniformAlphaTexture = glGetUniformLocation(shader->_program, "alphaTexture");
   ```
2. Shader update

   ```
   CCGLProgram *shader = mutableSprite.shaderProgram;
   [shader use];
   ccGLBindTexture2DN(1, alphaSprite.texture.name);
   glUniform1i(uniformAlphaTexture, 1);
   ```

So I'm sending alphaSprite to the shader. The first time it looks fine but after adding holes(rgba) to alphaSprite and calling code #2 there is no update of texture inside the shader, it still uses initial alphaSprite texture.

Comment: Might be some issue such as active texture. I use same shaders swapping textures all the time. Also I hope this all happens on the same thread...

Comment: You're right. Code is correct, I tried to randomize input textures from main bundle and it works fine.
Is it correct to send all this stuff to a background thread?

Comment: It should be ok, but if you want to do that there are a few more things you need to do. Each thread should have its own context so at some point you have to create a context on a background thread as well and set it as a current context. To use the content crated with another context you will need to create a context "share group" and bind both contexts to it. Try looking at this for a moment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html